# Equation number too close to my equation

Tags: equations, numbering

My equation number is being placed directly below my equation, so close they're almost touching and it looks really bad. Is there any way that I can get it to move down a little bit? Here's a picture.

[image: the problem]

My code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

The elementary solution is

\begin{equation}
f(\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))=k(z,w)=%
\frac{%
e^{-t/4}\sqrt{2}}{(4\pi{}t)^{3/2}}\int_{\rho_{H}(z,w)}^{\infty}{\frac{be^{-b^{-2}/4t}db}{%
\sqrt{\cosh(b)-\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))}}}.
\end{equation}

Further text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: output]

Please always post complete documents not just fragments, as the setting depends on the class used as much as the equation.

You can add a rule to force the number down, or perhaps better set the equation on more than one line. As @egreg notes if you are using AMS environments (but apparently not `equation`) you can use `\raisetag` to lower the number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{50}

\begin{equation}
f(\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))=k(z,w)=
\frac{e^{-t/4}\sqrt{2}}{(4\pi{}t)^{3/2}}\int_{\rho_{H}(z,w)}^{\infty}{\frac{be^{-b^{-2}/4t}db}{\sqrt{\cosh(b)-\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))}}}.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f(\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))=k(z,w)=
\frac{e^{-t/4}\sqrt{2}}{(4\pi{}t)^{3/2}}\int_{\rho_{H}(z,w)}^{\infty}{\frac{be^{-b^{-2}/4t}db}{\sqrt{\cosh(b)-\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))}}}.\rule[-1.5em]{0pt}{0pt}
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
f(\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))=k(z,w)=
\frac{e^{-t/4}\sqrt{2}}{(4\pi{}t)^{3/2}}\int_{\rho_{H}(z,w)}^{\infty}{\frac{be^{-b^{-2}/4t}db}{\sqrt{\cosh(b)-\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))}}}.
\raisetag{-.5em}
\end{gather}

\begin{multline}
f(\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))=k(z,w)=\\
\frac{e^{-t/4}\sqrt{2}}{(4\pi{}t)^{3/2}}\int_{\rho_{H}(z,w)}^{\infty}{\frac{be^{-b^{-2}/4t}db}{\sqrt{\cosh(b)-\cosh(\rho_{H}(z,w))}}}.
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Sorry I've edited my question. Working in the report class.

Comment: `amsmath` provides `\raisetag` for moving the equation number up or, as asked here, down.

Comment: @egreg so it does, actually in my defence I only added amsmath after the rule example to demonstrate multline.

Comment: It appears that `\raisetag` is somewhat buggy: the equation number protrudes into the right margin! (Ping, @egreg.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt well spotted so it does better ping barbara...

Comment: @HendrikVogt I don't think so; the equation doesn't fill the line; try with `\usepackage{showframe}` or `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}` to see the margin.

Comment: @egreg I updated the image with raisetag example, whatever the margins the raisetag label (53) is displaced horizontally which doesn't seem right

Comment: It appears that `multline` and not `\raisetag` causes the problem. If you replace `multline` with `gather`, then everything is nice. (@egreg: It doesn't _always_ apply, but as a principle I try and test before I post comments like these! And I try to be precise in my formulations: I only formulated the 2nd part of my previous comment as a fact `:-)`)

Comment: @HendrikVogt -- if you could send me, off-line, the example that you tested, i'll put it into our queue.  (we already have some complaints posted about `\raisetag`, but we're always looking for good test files.)  i'm adding a pointer to this item right now, so it won't be overlooked.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it seems `\raisetag` isn't really involved but if you have a single line wide multline in which the label moves down, it moves to the right as well, multi-line multlines seem OK see also chat with egreg: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=8416122#8416122

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I sent you an e-mail with an example file nevertheless. (Is _e-mail_ off-line enough? `:-)`) EDIT: It appears that `multline` just _mustn't_ be used for one-line equations (which is reasonable ...). The output is even more funny if the equation is quite short: then `multline` spreads it almost over the full line width. David, I think it's best if you replace `multline` with `gather` or so.

Comment: @HendrikVogt -- yes, e-mail is indeed what i meant.  thanks.  and regarding one-line equations, this is another reason we recommend not to use `align` with just one line.  but some people are lazy.